# update with exists in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, sql-update, exists

I have this query :

```
update rexcms e
   set e.cocnd=(select r.cocnd
                  from rexcms r
                 where NVL(r.marche,'*')=NVL(e.marche,'*')
                   and r.cocrd= e.cocrd
                   and r.cocol=e.cocol
                   and r.cocol='CHBIL'
                   and r.marche='CBOT')
 where e.cocol ='CDVHB' ;
```

how can use EXISTS to optimize it

Comment: You seem to have a misconception of what `EXISTS` is. `EXISTS` is not a tool to optimize a query. It is meant to add lookup criteria to a query. So, if you put `EXISTS` into your update statement, you wouldn't enhance it, but change it (by limiting the updated rows to rows for which exists <some row in some table that matches certain criteria>).

Comment: Exactly how can i write my query with using the exixts can you help me? PLZ

Comment: You still don't understand. `EXISTS` changes your query. If you want to update only rows where the cocnd exists in the table abc, then you'd add `and exists (select null from abc where abc.cocnd = e.cocnd)`, but if you only want to update rows where the marche exists in the marches table then you'd add `and exists (select null from marches where marches.marche = e.marche)`. How am I supposed to know in which way you want to change what your query does? I cannot read minds.

Comment: i undrestabd now an correct my query thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, This is optimized code. There is one more syntax as MERGE that you can use to achieve the result -

```
MERGE INTO rexcms e
USING rexcms r
   ON (NVL(r.marche,'*') = NVL(e.marche,'*')
       and r.cocrd = e.cocrd
       and r.cocol = e.cocol
       and r.cocol = 'CHBIL'
       and r.marche = 'CBOT')
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
                      SET e.cocnd = r.cocnd
                    WHERE e.cocol ='CDVHB';
```

Comment: you mean :UPDATE rexcms e
SET
    e.cocnd = (
        SELECT
            r.cocnd
        FROM
            rexpmj r
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rexpmj r WHERE
            nvl(r.marche, '*') = nvl(  e.marche, '*' )
            AND r.cocrd = e.cocrd
            AND r.cocol = e.cocol
            AND r.cocol = 'CHBIL'
            AND r.marche = 'CBOT'))
    
WHERE
    e.cocol = 'CDVHB';   ??

Comment: Yes. Your code seems optimized. But do try the above code to compare the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

You update the table from rows of the same table. With `where e.cocol = 'CDVHB'` you only update CDVHB rows. With `r.cocol = e.cocol` you only update them with data from CDVHB rows. With `r.cocol = 'CHBIL'` you say that these rows must be CHBIL rows. But a row cannot be a CDVHB and a CHBIL row at the same time, because a row's `cocol` can only be one or the other.

Your query can hence be reduced to:

```
update rexcms set cocnd = null where cocol = 'CDVHB';
```

and there is no need for further optimization.

Comment: cocnd = null IS NOT NULL i must get it from (select r.cocnd
                  from rexcms r
                 where NVL(r.marche,'*')=NVL(e.marche,'*')
                   and r.cocrd= e.cocrd
                   and r.cocol=e.cocol
                   and r.cocol='CHBIL'
                   and r.marche='CBOT')     so i want to know how can enhance it using the exists clause

Comment: No, I am telling you that your update statement does exactly the same thing as mine: setting all CDVHB rows' cocnd to null, because your subquery is not capable of returning any value, as no row can match your criteria. There is nothing to enhance this. What kind of enhancement would that be? If you don't want to make this update, then just don't run it. And if you want another update, then you need another update statement in the first place.